# How can I pin the new Twitter app to the start screen?

Tags: twitter

In a [recent blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2013/02/26/a-better-twitter-for-windows-phone-arrives.aspx), it says that the new [official Twitter app](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=0b792c7c-14dc-df11-a844-00237de2db9e) has live tile support:

> Live Tile support
>
> Now you can pin Twitter accounts, lists, and searches to Start.

Even on the page in the marketplacce, the feature is described as:

> - Integrated right into your Windows Phone with faster performance, lock screen, and custom Live Tile that show your notifications
> - Direct access to your favorite profiles and lists optimizing Windows Phone "pinning" functionality

However, nowhere does it say *how* to pin your account (etc.) to your start screen to get the "Live Tile that show your notifications", so how do you pin an account to the start screen?

Comment: The confusion is in the word, account. It's meant to be as described in the answer above, pinning accounts/profiles, lists or searches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently using the version 3.0.0.20499. Windows Phone 8

Open the app and click in the person icon (the profile image). Right now you are in the profile page.

In the options in the bottom you must have home, compose, search and pin.

[image]

Comment: That's the "Direct access to your favorite profiles and lists optimizing Windows Phone "pinning" functionality" rather than the "Integrated right into your Windows Phone with faster performance, lock screen, and custom Live Tile that show your notifications"?

Comment: Marketing guys, you know. But yes, it is the only way. Looks like a Me tile form another person but only with twitter.

Comment: Whilst not the answer I wanted, it is the (only) correct answer at the moment, per @CharlesWu (who wrote [the announcement on the twitter blog](http://blog.twitter.com/2013/02/an-update-to-twitter-for-windows-phone.html), so I guess we can trust him :)